# Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql, asp.net

This error is occurring on every *.asp page in the application, but the *.aspx pages work just fine.

I did not develop the application, but the person who did has long since left the company. We have about 20 customers, all with the program working just fine. One of the customers had their server crash, and we had to re-set it up on their new server. Everything is working just fine now, except for this error on the *.asp pages.

The same connection string is used for all of our customers, so I know the problem is not there. There are no system DSNs or user DSNs defined on *any* of our customers.

This is a 32-bit application on a 32-bit server (server 2003 with SQL 2005).

I'm pretty sure it's a permissions or setting error, but I have checked absolutely everything I can think of.

Please help.
A company with 1400 employees can't use this program until I get it back up and running. I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: can you provide the connection string you use please, the few lines of code that open the connection would be useful too

Comment: Your question is too general, what is the specific problem? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.
Sorry it took me a little bit to respond to you, but I had heard back from the original developer, and he had a hidden connection string deep within the program specifically to trip someone up if they were trying to install the program without authorization.  He gave me the info I needed and it worked beautifully.

Thanks again!